# Yulewalker with GNU Octave

Tags: signal-processing, octave

I'm trying to design yulewalk filters.

MATLAB has a [yulewalk](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/yulewalk.html) function:

```
[b,a] = yulewalk(n,f,m)
```

Octave's yulewalker, however, is quite different:

```
[a, v] = yulewalker (c)
```

The documentation at https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Signal-Processing.html (all the way to the bottom) is not too helpful...

I have all data needed by MATLAB, but I'm guessing I need to further process it somehow in order to feed it to Octave. Anyone knows how? Does someone have an example?

Comment: If you have access to MATLAB, the `yulewalk` function is open source, so you could probably just copy it and run it in octave with only minor modifications.

Comment: @Dev-iL wut? I've never seen an open-source function from MATLAB

Comment: @Andy I never said it was "free" or "public domain", merely that the source code is visible (hence "open"). Perhaps a wrong choice of terminology on my behalf.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have it, I just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the yulewalk function : http://read.pudn.com/downloads48/sourcecode/math/163974/yulewalk.m__.htm

Make sure you **run '`pkgload signal`'** before using the function in octave.